# Do $\|f-h_n\|_2\to 0$ and $\forall x\in (0,1) ; \lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=g(x)$ imply $f=g$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

The question of $L^2$ norm (defined by $\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(y)|^2 dy}$) and pointwise convergence.

Let $f,g :(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ be functions and $\{h_n :(0,1)\to \mathbb R\}$ be a sequence of functions.

If $\|f-h_n\|_2\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $\forall x\in (0,1) ; \lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)=g(x)$, then does $f=g$ hold ?

My approach is here, simply tried to prove by epsilon argument.

The claim is $\forall x\in(0,1)$ ; $f(x)=g(x)$, so at first, fix $x\in (0,1)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

From the supposition, I have $N_1\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $n\geqq N_1$ implies $\|f-h_n\|_2<\epsilon$, and $N_2\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $n\geqq N_2$ implies $|h_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon.$

Let $N=\max \{N_1, N_2\}$ and then $|f(x)-g(x)|\leqq |f(x)-h_N(x)|+|h_N(x)-g(x)|<|f(x)-h_N(x)|+\epsilon$.

If I have $|f(x)-h_N(x)|\leqq \|f-h_N\|_2$, the proof finishes, but I cannot see this.

Comment: You can only get $f=g$ a.e.: Convergence in $L^2$ implies almost everywhere convergence (for a subsequence) hence...

Comment: Stab in the dark: are you assuming the functions are continuous? Without further assumptions, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is really a *seminorm*, rather than a norm (since $\|f\|_2 = 0$ does not imply $f(x) = 0$ everywhere), on the space of square-integrable functions, and Rohan's answer is all that needs to be pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f=g$ need not be true. However you get $f=g$ almost everywhere. That is because $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{p}} f\implies$ there exist a subsequence $f_{n_{k}}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{a.e} f$ .So you can change the values of $f$ for a set of measure zero but you'll still get $L^{2}$ and almost everywhere convergence.

Example:-

Let $f_{n}=\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$ . Then $||f_{n}-0||_{2}=(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}\to 0$

So I can define $f=0$ . But I can also define $f(x)=\begin{cases}1\,,x\in\Bbb{Q}\\ 0 \,,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$ . Then also we get $||f_{n}-f||_{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be true, because even if you changed $g$ at finitely many points, $h_n$ would still converge to $f$ in the $L_2$ norm

Answer (score 0):

We can only conclude that $f=g$ a.e.

Denote $F_{n}=f-h_{n}$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $||F_{n}||_{2}\rightarrow0\Rightarrow||F_{n}||_{1}\rightarrow0$.
(For, $\int_{0}^{1}|F_{n}|=\int_{0}^{1}|F_{n}\cdot1|\leq\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}|F_{n}|^{2}}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}|1|^{2}}\rightarrow0$.)

By Vitali's theorem, $||F_{n}||_{1}\rightarrow0\Rightarrow$ there
exists a subsequence $(F_{n_{k}})$ such that $F_{n_{k}}\rightarrow0$
pointwisely a.e.. That is, there exist a measurable set $A$ with
$m((0,1)\setminus A)=0$ and a subsequence $(F_{n_{k}})$ such that
for each $x\in A$, $F_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
On the other hand, it is given that $h_{n}(x)\rightarrow g(x)$, so
$h_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow g(x)$. Therefore, $f(x)-g(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(x)-h_{n_{k}}(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}F_{n_{k}}(x)=0$.

I state and prove the Vitali's theorem for your reference.

Theorem: Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $(f_{n})$
be a sequence of integrable functions defined on $X$. If $\int|f_{n}|d\mu\rightarrow0$,
then there exist $A\in\mathcal{M}$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$
such that $\mu(A^{c})=0$ and $f_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow0$ for each
$x\in A$.

Proof: Choose $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots<n_{k}<\ldots$ recursively such
that $\int|f_{n_{k}}|\leq\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ for all $k$. We go to
show that $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow0$ pointwisely a.e. To ease typing,
denote $g_{k}=f_{n_{k}}$. Let $A=\{x\in X\mid g_{k}(x)\rightarrow0\}$,
then
$$
A^{c}=\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)}\cap_{K}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\}.
$$
Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)$ be arbitrary. We go to show that
$\cap_{K}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\}$ has measure
zero. Let $B_{k}=\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\}$. Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
r\mu(B_{k}) & \leq & \int_{B_{k}}|g_{k}|\\
 & \leq & \int|g_{k}|\\
 & \leq & \frac{1}{2^{k}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu\left(\cup_{k\geq K}\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\}\right) & \leq & \sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\mu(B_{k})\\
 & \leq & \frac{1}{r}\sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\mu(\cap_{K}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\})\leq\frac{1}{r}\sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}$.
Since $K$ on the RHS is arbitrary, by letting $K\rightarrow\infty$, we conclude
that $\mu\left(\cap_{K}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x\in X\mid|g_{k}(x)|\geq r\}\right)=0$.